# Setting feature limit on WFS request

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, sql, wfs, features

I am connecting to a WFS Layer and within the SQL Statement I want to *limit* the response from the server:

[image: WFS Layer]

That gives me a syntax error:

> Wrong SQL. Syntaxerror. NUMBER_INT is not expected. $end is expected.

How do I limit the features that return from the WFS layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried specifying max returned features in the WFS connection window?

[image]

Comment: Nope, that is not working either. It says `statement must start with SELECT`. That is the WFS by the way. Its public https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_wfs_adressenberlin

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you running @Stohpface? I just queried that WFS layer using both methods and I got a valid response running QGIS 3.12.1

Comment: I use `3.16. 3 `

Comment: See the edits. Have you tried the Processing Toolbox - Vector General - Execute SQL tool?

Comment: I just saw it. How do you add the WFS Layer there? I have not added the WFS layer, because when I add it, QGIS crashes. It has too many features. That is why I want to limit it...

Comment: Have you tried running the query in the dialog appearing (where I made the screenshot) under `Layer - Add Layer - Add WFS Layer` ?

Comment: Oh, yeah I get the same errors there. But I was able to limit by 1000 in the ADD WFS Layer - Modify Layer by setting max. number of features to 1000. Does that not work for you?

Comment: Damn, I did not know that there is such a feature... I though I have to limit it through `SQL`. Thanks! That worked!

Comment: I just changed the answer to remove all the Execute SQL stuff.